# What is the optimized way of finding and replacing specific set of strings in a lengthy string?

Tags: java, string, optimization, replace

I need to obfuscate values of parameters matching

```
password, tokenID
```

Sample query string:

```
visitorNo=89&password=demo&tokenID=yxr56
```

Should be obfuscated to:

```
visitorNo=89&password=$$&tokenID=$$
```

What I did:

```
String[] parameters = queryString.split("&");
StringBuffer qS = new StringBuffer();
for(String param : parameters) {
    String[] keyValue = param.split("=");
    qS.append(keyValue[0]);
    qS.append("=");
    for(String paramToObfuscate : paramsToObfuscate) {
        if(paramToObfuscate.equals(keyValue[0])) {
            qS.append("$$");
        }
        else {
            qS.append(keyValue[1]);
        }
    }
    qS.append("&");
}

String queryStr = qS.toString().substring(0, qS.length-1);
```

Comment: @NiklasB. It works. Wonder if this can be achieved in some more optimized way.

Comment: What if `paramsToObfuscate.length > 1`? Unless I'm stupid it shouldn't work in that case. Say `paramsToObfuscate = { "password", "tokenID"`, you should get `visitorNo=8989&password=$$<unobfuscated password>&tokenID=<unobfuscated token>$$` Not a very effective obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only two parameters, there's no faster way. If there were tens of them, you could use

```
Set<String> paramsToObfuscate = new HashSet<String>();
```

and `Set.contains`, which is surely faster than tens of tests.